# Building Datadog facets from an array of json objects

Tags: json, datadog

I am trying to build Datadog facets from an array of json objects but I have to build a string builder and a grok parser in order to accomplish this. The log field looks something like the following. How do extract this data and build an array from this that I can great facets to be viewed in the dashboard? I know how to accomplish this if array only had one field foe example the name field. But since it has both name and value how can I make this happen?

LOG FIELD EXAMPLE

root_field [
0 {
name    xxxxx
value   11111
},
1 {
name    yyyyy
value   22222
},
2 {
name    zzzzz
value   33333
}
]